# How to wrap long text of MSBuild error task in csproj file

Tags: .net, msbuild, csproj, msbuild-task

For example, I have the following line in my `csproj`:

```
<Error Text="Here is my very very long description of the exception that should explain how to fix it, make life better and give an answer to the meaning of life..." />
```

The problem this message is very long and it's hard to read the code, review in GitHub etc.

I have tried the following:

```
<Error Text="Here is my very very long description of the exception
    that should explain how to fix it, make life better
    and give an answer to the meaning of life..." />
```

But the output in this case is not readable because each line have redundant information about `build target` or `csproj` file name.

Therefore I want to have something like:

```
<Error Text="Here is my very very long description of the exception" +
    "that should explain how to fix it, make life better" +
    "and give an answer to the meaning of life..." />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the lines in an ItemGroup and join them together:

```
<Target Name="LongError">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Lines Include="abc"/>
    <Lines Include="def"/>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Error Text="@(Lines, ' ')" />
</Target>
```